# Creating child view models when using MEF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

I have a traditional MVVM approach, so for example a view model called 'PatientManagementViewModel' that is used by a view called 'PatientManagementView'. Everything is injected using MEF, so I don't create any instance myself.

Now suppose that 'PatientManagementViewModel' has a property Patients, which is an ObervableCollection of 'PatientViewModel'. What I do now to create an instance of 'PatientViewModel' and pass the selected patient is like:

```
var patientViewModel = _container.GetExportedValue<IPatientViewModel>();
patientViewModel.Patient = patient;
```

This works, however, I was wondering if this makes sense. It would be nicer to pass a patient to the constructor because 'PatientViewModel' cannot exist without a Patient:

```
var patientViewModel = new PatientViewModel(patient);
```

but then I can't use dependency injection.

So the question is: does it make sense to inject a subviewmodel, or should I only inject the main view model, and instantiate all subviewmodels without injection?

Comment: 'PatientManagementViewModel' has a property Patients, which is an ObervableCollection of 'PatientViewModel' <= I think you should think about your application design again.

Comment: Can you explain? I don't see what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. You can create your child view model using usual constructor and then call `ComposeParts` on the instance to inject everything:

```
var patientViewModel = new PatientViewModel(patient);
_container.ComposeParts(patientViewModel);
```

But doing this every time is not very good for a variety of reasons. To address this scenario and to encapsulate usage of MEF I created a helper service for creating view models. It is called `IViewModelFactory` and here is how it looks:

```
[Export(typeof(IViewModelFactory))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
internal class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ViewModelFactory(CompositionContainer container) {
        Contract.Requires(container != null);

        Container = container;
    }

    protected CompositionContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public T Create<T>(params object[] args) where T : class {
        T result;

        try {
            bool populateDependencies = false;

            if (args == null || args.Length == 0) {
                // There are no parameters for contructor, so
                // try to create an instance by asking the container.
                result = Container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<T>();

                if (result == null) {
                    // The view model is not exported. Just create an instance using reflection
                    // and then populate all the dependencied using the container.
                    result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    populateDependencies = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                // There are constructor parameters. Create an instance using those parameters
                // and then populate all the dependencied using the container.
                result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
                populateDependencies = true;
            }

            // Populate dependencies if needed
            if (populateDependencies) {
                Container.ComposeParts(result);
            }

            // Initialize the object if applicable
            var initializable = result as IInitializable;

            if (initializable != null) {
                initializable.Initialize();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            throw new ViewModelCreationException(
                string.Format(
                    "Unable to create and configure an instance of view model of type {0}. An error occured. See inner exception for details.",
                    typeof (T)), ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Using this factory you can create child view models like this:

```
var patientViewModel = ViewModelFactory.Create<PatientViewModel>(patient);
```

The downside here is that, when you use constructor parameters, you loose compile-time check for the parameters' types, count, order etc.

Comment: ExportFactory would make this cleaner.  It's not supported in the .NET 4 release of MEF, but the next version will have it, and the Codeplex preview version and Silverlight already have it.

Comment: @Daniel - Interesting... Could you provide a link?

Comment: http://mef.codeplex.com and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807(VS.95).aspx